# flex-grow isn't rendering correctly in Internet Explorer 11 (IE11)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I tried a new html design with flex boxes. The design in Chrome 58 Version 58.0.3029.110 is correct but not in IE11. I did not tried other browsers.

What is the issue?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#left {
  flex: 6 0%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#right {
  flex: 1 0%;
  background-color: black;
}

#top {
  flex: 1 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#nav {
  flex: 1 0%;
  background-color: green;
}

#main {
  flex: 6 0%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#notepad {
  flex: 1 0%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#chat {
  flex: 6 0%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#break {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div id="top">test</div>
  <div id="nav">test</div>
  <div id="main">test</div>
  <div id="break"></div>
  <div id="notepad">test</div>
  <div id="chat">test</div>
</div>
<div id="right">test</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/25qu0b2p/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary problem is that IE11 is riddled with flexbox-related bugs ([**flexbugs**](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)).

The specific problem is that `flex-grow` isn't strong enough to get flex items to wrap in IE11.

You have this rule in your code: `flex: 1 100%`. It uses a shorthand property that breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1` ([by default](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-shrink))
- `flex-basis: 100%`

Because you've set `flex-basis` to `100%`, and the container is set to `wrap`, that **should** be enough to get subsequent items to wrap.

Since `flex-basis: 100%` consumes all space in the row, there's no space remaining for other items. So they must wrap. Chrome gets this.

However, IE11, for whatever reason, sees subsequent items set to `flex: 1 0%` and says this:

> *Okay, `flex-grow` is set to `1`, but there's no free space on the line. So there's no space to distribute. And `flex-basis` is set to `0`. This item must be `width: 0`. No need to wrap anything.*

To workaround this logic, while maintaining cross-browser compatibility, add some width to items that must wrap. Try `flex-basis: 1px` instead of `flex-basis: 0`.

```
#nav {
  flex: 1 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

#notepad {
  flex: 1 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/25qu0b2p/1/)

Comment: Great explanation, I like the part when you impersonate IE